# Matplotlib question: x labels on top of each other. How to space the x label for readability

Tags: matplotlib

Quite new to plotting in Python and I have run into an issue where the x label of my pyplot are written on top of each other. Is there a way to space the x label so it becomes clear to read?

[image: The image on the link]

My code is here:

```
plt.bar(app_state_fum['STATE'],app_state_fum['age_sum'],color='b')
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your ticks labels:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

or

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

[image]